# cost of replacing complete plumbing stack

Tags: plumbing

Approximate cost of replacing full main drain stack from metal to PVC on two story residential home including all branch fixtures, toilets sinks etc..Cudahy,WI

This is a complete assignment from beginning to end opening walls, 3 fixtures per floor 30 ft run.Two floors. Good ball park dollar amount. I know I will need estimate.s from other licensed plumbers and contractors

Comment: That's going to depend on the size and shape of the building, how it's constructed, whether you've already opened up walls and such for other work, local costs of labor -- You need quotes from local plumbing contractors after they've seen what's actually going to be involved.

Comment: This is a complete assignment from beginning to end, 3 fixtures per floor 30 ft run.Two floors. Good ball park dollar amount. I know I will need estimate.s from other licensed plumbers and contractors thanks for your info

Comment: Which part of no ballpark can be given sight unseen over the internet are you failing to get? Also, this type of question is specifically off-topic...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the price of a job.

Answer (score 1):

Get a couple of estimates, calculate the average, and there you go.